# flutter carousel slider prevent first element from scrolling to center

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, carousel

I'm new to flutter, I want to create a carousel where you can scroll horizontally and no snapping of elements to the center, I did that, but it has whitespace to its sides, I want the first element to start on the left of the screen, when I try to scroll and get the first element to the center it stays to the left, but when I scroll the other way it scrolls normally, same thing with the last element, but sticks to the right not left.

This is what I have
[image: This is what I have]

This is what I want
[image: This is what I want]

Comment: Add your implementation code here, else your question might get negative voting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Carousel slider have no any property to set element centre to start on laft screen ,

If you don't want to use carousel slider then you can try this demo :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListviewSliderDemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListviewSliderDemoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListviewSliderDemoScreenState createState() =>
      _ListviewSliderDemoScreenState();
}

class _ListviewSliderDemoScreenState extends State<ListviewSliderDemoScreen> {
  final List<String> imageUrls = [
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682687982134-2ac563b2228b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567790350645-dbc1486a89c3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80',
    'https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1681584471485-0d12b119d3db?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797332-e678a04f8a64?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695794947-17061dc284dd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Carousel Slider Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: imageUrls.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 200,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      child: Image.network(
                        imageUrls[index],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```